# Why do I get errors of select proper boot device when using a cloned SSD?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bootloader, clone

After cloning a new SSD with Windows 10 installed on it using EaseUSTodoBackup, I removed an old SSD with Windows 10 installed on it and put it the new clone. The computer boots up fine. After a day or so, it suddenly seems to forget where the Windows 10 installation is. This is the second time this has happened to me when switching SSDs with a cloned SSD. Why is this?

Comment: I use macrium reflect free to clone drives and have not seen this issue using it so far.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll be sure to try that. On another note, can I rule out the issue being anything other than my clone/cloning software or is there something else I need to be aware of regarding why the BIOS cannot find the OS to boot when it was the only one installed and in a PC with a single SSD?